# Intercepting I/O on this simple vibration alarm / glass break alarm

Tags: sensor, wifi, vibration, alarm

I got these vibration alarms, but they're far too sensitive to leave as is.
I want to use HomeAssistant or something to get a notification and decide whether to trigger the alarm, and maybe do some additional processing to rule out false positives.

So I want to either desolder that chip and wire voltage/ground/io pins from an ESP32 board or at least just use the same chip and board, but intercept the inputs to the speaker and just send that to an ESP32 board instead, then wire outputs from the ESP32 back to the speaker.

I'm not sure what component is in the middle with the "1 -F-" on it, or how to wire this at all. I'm guessing a BJT or something to boost the speaker?
If anyone can see a way to do it without that chip on the board, that would probably be preferable to lower battery consumption, but otherwise, intercepting the speaker would do.[image: Upright View]
[image: Downside View]
[image: Side View]
[image: Side View]

Comment: As for the component with ``"1 -F-"``, it looks like might have heat-shrink tubing covering a 3 lead device. Can you try and get a picture from either of the ends of the tubing? I.e. the ``"1 -F-"`` might be the marking on the heat-shrink rather than the identity of the actual device.

Comment: Definitely 3 pin. Should've mentioned that. That's why I think it might be a metal cap BJT rather than a capacitor or something. Added side views from both sides to the original post.

Comment: If it was a BJT, I would assume the bottom pin that isn't connected to the voltage or ground of the piezo is the base, but that can't be right because A) The other 2 pins are only connected to the piezo, so where is the power coming from? B) That's not normally how a BJT is wired C), the bottom pin appears to be connected to V+ from the battery and a diode, not an IO signal from the MCU. Infact I don't see how it can be triggered by the MCU regardless of what it is, and yet it is. I must be missing something?

Comment: From the pictures the PCB could be two layers; since appears to be some vias. Is it possible to remove remove the PCB from the case and take a picture from the other side and/or trace the connections?

Comment: Just checked and the other side has no traces. Just the green soldermask and solder holding those couple of through-hole components.

Comment: Oh, it looks like this is the IO to the speaker, it just needs to go through the SPDT switch https://i.imgur.com/3r8BXdX.png

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be any voltage or ground though. Maybe it's amplifying the small current of the output signal.. with no ground? I'm also still not sure which are the sensor pins.

Comment: That 3 pin component looks like a simple inductor with drum core. Possibly centre tapped?

Comment: That checks out. They even sell 3 pin ones on aliexpress as "alarm boost inductors"
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006405791965.html and someone has documented it here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539843/how-does-the-component-alarm-boost-three-pin-inductor-make-a-piezo-buzzer-loud

Comment: Updated the 2nd picture on the original post for a clearer shot of the sensor circuit.
I'm still so confused by this, because it seems as though the piezo sensor, the sensitivity dial and the inductor input to the piezo speaker are all on the same circuit that's connected to one of the MCU's IO pins. It would make sense if this was just V+, but then I don't see how any of the IO pins can be connected to the MCU.
https://i.imgur.com/taevYpk.jpeg

Comment: Q3 is the driver for the transformer, so you will see a square wave at pin 5 of the MCU during an alarm.